# Getting from Leicester to Keswick

Tags: uk, public-transport, lake-district

We are planning to go to Keswick from Leicester next January. I am not sure which is the best way to travel there. I would prefer not renting a car but I am open to it if it is the best way. I am failing to find any train tickets available (from Leicester to Keswick(Bus Station)).

Comment: You won't get train tickets to Keswick, because there is no train station there. You' d have to get the train to Penrith, then a bus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The train doesn't go to Keswick. You should buy a train ticket to Penrith and then take a local bus. Check on http://www.traveline.info as it's the best website for public transport in the UK.

Comment: @pnuts sure about what? there are many ways to travel. he didn't mention the cheapest one and also with the trains in this country you just need to know how to book. you can go 10 mins earlier or later and pay 5 times more.

Comment: The train from Leicester to Penrith costs about £80 for a standard off-peak return (or even cheaper on an advanced ticket). Not sure how much the local bus costs. And total time of 5 hours. So not much more expensive than coach, and several hours quicker.

Comment: @pnuts I provided a website that lists different options and it's up the person who asked the question to decide if time or money is more important.

Answer (score 0):

A National Express coach journey from Leicester to Keswick, with a change in Birmingham, will take about 8 hours and set you back £50 for a single.

http://www.nationalexpress.com/home.aspx